# How to deal with websockets on IIS on port 80 in general and when using ISAPI

Tags: iis, websocket, isapi, port80

We are using IIS and ISAPI DLL's to deliver our web application.  We can see the websocket upgrade request coming from the browser in our ISAPI application.  We could accept the request and pass the connection to a thread to continue the conversation.  The thread would now be the "websocket server" so in this sense we are able to handle incoming http (and https on 443) then switch from http to websocket, is that right?

I am assuming Microsoft's implementation of websockets only works with asp.net?

Some people have said to me "put the websocket server on a different port and have the javascript connect to that port."  But, then the websocket server is not using HTTPS (SSL).

For example:
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');

I have lots of books and examples but this simple issue is eluding me.

Answer (score 0):

> The thread would now be the "websocket server" so in this sense we are able to handle incoming http (and https on 443) then switch from http to websocket, is that right?

Yes, if the client side send the request which contains the `Upgrade: websocket`, the websocket serve will switch from http to websocket.

> I am assuming Microsoft's implementation of websockets only works with asp.net?

If you means the websocket .net library, it will just work with .net application like asp.net, it is developed based on the .net framework.

> For example: var socket = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');

As far as I know, the websocket  also contains the secure connection like https.

Like below image shows:

[image]

More details about the difference between http and websocket, you could refer to below article:

https://developerinsider.co/difference-between-http-and-http-2-0-websocket/